# Reactjs - Rendering login component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow) on react routing. I managed to connect it to my data store, and it works fine.

What bothers me is the landing page. The way I have [set it up](https://jsfiddle.net/0t1nv1uv/)(Fiddle) it when the user goes to root page, link to login is displayed. When the user clicks that login the login form component is shown.

I would like to avoid clicking on the loginlink. When the user navigates to root page, if he is not logged in automatically display the Login component.

This [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z5z592x/) shows my futile attempt to make it work. 
Previous code that works:

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        {this.state.loggedIn ? (
          <Link to="/logout">Log out</Link>
        ) : (
          <Link to="/login">Sign in</Link>
        )}
      </li>
      <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link> (authenticated)</li>
    </ul>
    {this.props.children || <p>You are {!this.state.loggedIn && 'not'} logged in.</p>}
  </div>
)
}
```

And this is my attempt:

```
 render() {
return (
   <Login data={this.state} />
)
}
```

This actually render the login component, but produces this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

It seems it is disconnected.

I am breaking my head over this for some time now, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Variables passed to children the way you do with `data={something}` are called `props`.

You can access to `data` from within `<Login />` component with `this.props.data`

I highly suggest you to read this : https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your fiddle, i think this is wat you want to do.

```
    function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {

  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}

  render((
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route path="/" component={App} onEnter={requireAuth} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('example'));
```

btw i removed the nesting from your routes i didnt think they where necessary within your setup, but if you do readd them
i saw this peace of code in your fiddle, so actually the only thing you need to do is onEnter=requireAuth on app,
if your not logged in you will be going to login, if you are you will be going to your app,

so in our render you can do whatever u want

```
const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div> You are logged in </div>
    )
  }
});
```

a sidenote: the only thing u are doing here is passing your state object to a child component

```
return (
   <Login data={this.state} />
)
```

meaning:

within Login, the property this.props.data <-- now has the same values as this.state in the parent component of Login

Comment: Thank you for reply. When I use your code, it works but with a twist. After succesfull login, it only displays "You are logged in". I cant access any other routes, even when I type them in the URL... what could be wrong?

Comment: beause u have a seperate auth class, your authentication can be done outside, of your react component, the function u call within onEnther already handles the login flow for you, meaning, if you land on APP 

your entry path=/ then u can assume your are logged in otherwise you would always be redirected to /login <-

you can do the same for /about/dashboard if needed

Comment: Could you please provide an example? :)

Comment: I did . The modifications are in my post .

Comment: I am having problems inplementing the solution zou suggested. Now it redirects many times to login route, and gives Maximum call stack exceeded. Here is fiddle with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/jjja73wh/. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: As provided in my example, you can remove all state logic, and login logic from your app component you dont need it, you also dont need to render the login component within you app component. Your APP component is your initial route. (Your startpoint) before that route is visited (onEnter) it calls therequire auth function. This will call the auth class, and check if u are logged in. If you are it will render APP component, (see my example) APP component just says u Are logged in in its render function. If you are not logged in (the require auth function) will redirect you login)

Comment: I just cant get it to work. It just keeps redirecting to login component :(

Comment: Could u add your auth class to the fiddle and your current login component. I need to see what happens there

Comment: Here is complete App, Login and Auth class in the fiddle. Thank you. https://jsfiddle.net/wexoni/pw24pcnv/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105791/discussion-between-danillo-felixdaal-and-wexoni).